# How can I provide custom RequestOptionsArgs in Angular 2 in a request?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http

I have extended the Http service and overwritten methods such as

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
```

In this request method I have a loader that I show and Hide when the request starts and the request ends.

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.loadingService.start();

    if (!options) {
        options = {};
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    this.updateHeaders(options.headers);
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        this.updateHeaders(url.headers);
    }

    return super.request(url, options)
        .catch((response: Response) => this.authError(response))
        .finally(() => {
            this.loadingService.done();
        });
}
```

The loadingService starts and stops a loading indicator. But I don't want this loading indicator to show on all requests. I would like some requests to not show the loader. How can I achieve this?

The RequestOptionArgs is an interface

```
export interface RequestOptionsArgs {
    url?: string;
    method?: string | RequestMethod;
    search?: string | URLSearchParams;
    headers?: Headers;
    body?: any;
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    responseType?: ResponseContentType;
}
```

But I probably shouldn't use any of these variables as an way of telling whether or not to show the loading indicator.

What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a http request that uses `http` service in the service, you don't need to override the original service.

Then create two methods, one for `loadingService` and another non-`loadingService`.

```
requestWithLoading(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.loadingService.start();

    if (!options) {
        options = {};
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    this.updateHeaders(options.headers);
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        this.updateHeaders(url.headers);
    }

    return http.request(url, options)
        .catch((response: Response) => this.authError(response))
        .finally(() => {
            this.loadingService.done();
        });
}

requestNonLoading(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    if (!options) {
        options = {};
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    this.updateHeaders(options.headers);
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        this.updateHeaders(url.headers);
    }

    return http.request(url, options)
        .catch((response: Response) => this.authError(response))
        .finally(() => {});
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the original Http service and not extending is probably the best approach, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Solution :** `this.loadingService.start();` move into your component.

**2.Solution :** otherwise set one peram `isLoading :boolean = true` into service.

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs, isLoading:boolean = true): Observable<Response> {
  if(isLoading){
     this.loadingService.start();
   }


    if (!options) {
        options = {};
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    this.updateHeaders(options.headers);
    if (typeof url !== 'string') {
        this.updateHeaders(url.headers);
    }

    return super.request(url, options)
        .catch((response: Response) => this.authError(response))
        .finally(() => {
            this.loadingService.done();
        });
}
```

Set default value **true** and **false** based on which is more.